# When I tried to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10 "errors were encountered while processing systemd-shim"

Tags: package-management, upgrade

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 238478 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing systemd-shim (9-1bzr4ubuntu1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service to /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd by systemd-shim'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service' with
  different file '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-shim
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service` to  `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.bak` and do

```
 sudo apt upgrade
```